# How rem function works in matlab

Tags: matlab, division

I have a question about how the `rem()` function works in Matlab.

I have a sample code but I don't have Matlab to run it. So, I was studying the Matlab function [reference page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html). However, I don't really understand how `rem()` function is working.

First, how `rem()` function work? For example, if `rem(5,0.1)` then what should I get as value?

Second, does `rem` function handle 2x2 arrays? For example, I have an 2x2 array `a` and a 2x2 array `b`, can I do `rem(a,b)`?

Comment: Given that the third example on the page you've linked to is entitled "remainder of two arrays", might I suggest having a closer look? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `rem()` calculates the [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) after division. In the equation `a = qd + r`, the number `q` is the quotient and `r` is the remainder. The quotient `q` is a natural number, i.e. 0,1,2,3, etc, while the remainder `r` is in the range `0<=r<d`. When you call the function `rem(a,d)`, it evaluates this expression `a-qd<d` for all the natural numbers. When the condition is satisfied, it is output: `r=a-qd`.

The arguments can be single numbers, arrays or matrices. For example, if you execute:

```
a = rem(0:10,3);
b = rem(0:10,4);
c = rem([1 2; 3 4],[4 3; 2 1]);
d = rem(5, 0.1);
e = rem(0.05, 0.1);
```

You get:

```
a = [0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1];
b = [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2];
c = [1 2;1 0];
d = 0;
e = 0.05;
```

Comment: Thanks it really really help me to understand :)